# Clear both content and checkboxes from the first n sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know there are the functions `getSheetId()` and `getSheetByName()`, but the name of the spreadsheets may change over time and they wouldn't apply anymore (or maybe they get deleted).

Is there a way to get the first ten sheets, except the last two (10 -2)? I want to create a reset button that will clear all fields from specific range, but I can't attach the function to a specific name. The last two spreadsheets can't be included in this function because they can't lose data.

Here it's the script that clears text cells in a single spreadsheet, but it doesn't work for clearing FALSE cells (checkboxes):

```
function ClearCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Master');
  sheet.getRange('C5:C34').clearContent();
   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution to the updated question:

You can use [removeCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removecheckboxes) to delete the checkboxes:

```
function ClearCells() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const sheets = ss.getSheets().slice(0,10);
   sheets.forEach(sh=>
     {
       sh.getRange('C5:C34').clearContent();
       sh.getRange('C5:C34').removeCheckboxes();
     }
   );
}
```

---

**References:**

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#:%7E:text=The%20slice()%20method%20returns,array%20will%20not%20be%20modified.)
- [removeCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removecheckboxes)

Comment: Does it have anything special for better performance?

Comment: I tried here but it's not cleaning cells with FALSE value (checkboxes) and those that were TRUE (checked) just became unchecked. Can you help clearing everything? The main purpose of the function is to really remove checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, the point is that when I saw that working for all the sheets, I realized that didn't solve the problem. I edited now, thanks. And if you could help, I'd appreciate.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can work.

```
function ClearCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i=0; i<10 && i<sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].getRange('C5:C34').clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but, but I got: ReferenceError: s is not defined (line 5, file "Code"). Can you please check?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos he meant i instead of s inside the for loop.